# How do i create the next download file name each time + 1 value?

Tags: c#, .net

The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTime.Count; i++)
{
    string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    link = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + selectedregion + "&time=" + result + "&ir=" +
    infraredorvisual;
    Next_Sat_File = satimagesdir + "\\" + "SatImage" + (i + lastsatimage.ToString("D6")) + ".gif";
}
```

I want to generate `Next_Sat_File`. my problem is that the variable `i` is first time 0 but I need it to be 1. 
Since the `lastsatimage` is `845` so the next file should be `SatImage000846` and then the next file after `SatImage000847`...

In the loop `dateTime` contain 9 files to download. From 0 to 8.
And if i will change it to start from 1 in the loop then i will miss one file.

Comment: Look up how to use the `string.Format()` Function

Comment: Next_Sat_File = satimagesdir + "\\" + "SatImage" + (i + lastsatimage.ToString("D6") + 1) + ".gif"; ?

Comment: Gosha nope this will add the number 1 as: SatImage0008451.gif it should add 1 to the number from 000845 to 000846.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just add one to `i` when it is needed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTime.Count; i++)
{
    string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    link = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + selectedregion + "&time=" + result + "&ir=" +
    infraredorvisual;
    Next_Sat_File = satimagesdir + "\\" + "SatImage" + (lastsatimage + i + 1).ToString("D6") + ".gif";
}
```

also try using `string.Format` instead of string concatenation. It increases your code readability.

```
Next_Sat_File = string.Format("{0}\\SatImage{1:D6}.gif", satimagesdir,
                      lastsatimage + i + 1);
```

Comment: Do you get index out of range at string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"); ?

Comment: doctor nope look at my comment to Aliminator.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to use `i` for indexing and labeling. Use `i` for indexing and for the labeling do (`i`+1 + lastsatimage) so when it is 0, it will be 1 and so on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTime.Count; i++)
{
    string result = dateTime[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    link = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + selectedregion + "&time=" + result + "&ir=" +
    infraredorvisual;
    Next_Sat_File = satimagesdir + "\\" + "SatImage" + ((i + 1 + lastsatimage).ToString("D6")) + ".gif";
}
```

Comment: Nope what i'm getting this way is: C:\Users\chocolade1972\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\satelliteImages\SatImage1000845.gif and the next file name should be: SatImage000846.gif but instead it's adding 1 just before the number it should add it like math to the number.

Comment: lastsatimage is the last 3 digits of the number for example 845 and with the D6 it's 000845 and + 1 should give the next file 000846 so in the end it should be: SatImage000846.gif and then next itertion SatImage000847.gif...and so on.

Comment: fixed, is that what you want? @Halem Shoshi